# Grabbing rows that are past a certain timestamp value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query for MySQL which I think should work:

```
SELECT nid, from_state, state, stamp WHERE stamp > 1396603396;
```

However Sequel Pro is giving me an error of "you have an error in your sql syntax".

I'm looking at the documentation page for comparison operators for MySQL and as far as I can tell, this SHOULD work.

The column stamp is an integer value.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the table name you want to select from

```
SELECT nid, from_state, state, stamp 
FROM your_table
WHERE stamp < 1396603396;
```